# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf, connect new formatter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am buidling application on top of the Spring Boot. At this point I've decided to use Thymeleaf to render some of the messages in this application. The application uses Thymeleaf configuration to render template provided as String's.

This is the Thymeleaf configuration:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    final SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setDialect(templateDialect());
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

    return engine;
}

@Bean
public StringTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final StringTemplateResolver templateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringStandardDialect templateDialect() {
    final SpringStandardDialect dialect = new SpringStandardDialect();
    dialect.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

    return dialect;
}
```

This is code that I use for rendering:

```
final Context context = new Context();

    context.setVariables(/*provide map with "variable" in it*/);

    return engine.process("[[${variable}]]", context);
```

The problem occurs when i try to process a list object. I want to add Formatter for the list type so it can be rendered in a right way. I've tried to do it using WebMvcConfigurer class by overriding method: AddFormatters with no success so far.

Comment: Why do you want to use Thymeleaf for this? You can also do replacement with regular messages from a `MessageSource`.

Comment: How is the MessageSource capable of processing template containing multiple varaibles in a single context including method invocation inside of the templates? Thymeleaf provides all of this. I am not sure about the MessageSource.

Comment: It can support as many variables you want... The method invocation might be an issue, but should you do method invocations in a message template in the first place or should it just proces the model?